# RestTemplate GET method with path variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httpclient, resttemplate

I am trying to make rest call using rest template. I have two header parameters and one path variable to set for the API call. Below is my implementation. But I am receiving HttpServerErrorException: 500 null. Am I setting the path variable in the right way?

Target API: drs/v1/{caseId}

```
String url = configProperties.getCaseCreateUrl();
                if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(url)){
                        url = url.replace(ApplicationConstants.DOMAIN_NAME,currentUser.domainUrl());
                        url = url+ caseId;
                }
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.set(ApplicationConstants.PS_TOKEN_HEADER, currentUser.getToken());
                headers.set(ApplicationConstants.WORGROUP_HEADER, currentUser.getWorkgroupId());
                headers.set(ApplicationConstants.DOMAIN_HEADER, currentUser.getDomainId());
                headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.ALL_VALUE);
                HttpsTrustManager.allowAllSSL();
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                HttpEntity<Map<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity(null, headers);
                ResponseEntity<CaseDetailsDTO> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, CaseDetailsDTO.class);
```

Comment: url = url+ caseId; should be url = url+ "/" + caseId;

Comment: 500 is thrown when your upstream service has an internal errors. Probably you need to check your upstream service logs

Comment: url is already trailing with "/" so I don't have to add. I don't see any internal error other than 500 null. Any idea how do I enable upstream logs?

Comment: 500 means server error. Worry about server first before worrying about your request.

Comment: Could you post any logs? That would help in narrowing down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing a code snippet of RestTemplate GET method with path variables example

```
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getNames(long id) {
        
            final String url = "https://some/{id}/name";
            //with cookies
            ResponseEntity<String> cookie = getCookies();
            
            String set_cookie = cookie.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.add("Cookie", set_cookie);
            HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);
            
            ResponseEntity<List<String>> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request,new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>(){},id);
            return response;
    }
```